# User account is locked when signing in Spring Securty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I followed this guide [Spring boot security + JWT](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world) in order to learn how to secure an application using spring boot security and jwt and i am calling the /authenticate api to test login functionality.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody User authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
    authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
            .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
}
private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    } catch (DisabledException e) {
        throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
    }
}
```

I am using postman to call the api passing username and password in json :

```
{
"username":"user",
"password":"pass"}
```

AuthenticationManager.authenticate is throwing User is Locked

My implementation of UserDetails is directly on a User Entity, not the best practices but i didnt have a better idea for how to do it now, maybe i should have some kind of DTO that implements is and have it as argument to createAuthenticationToken()

These are the overriden methods comming from UserDetails:

```
    @Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return false;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[isAccountNonLocked](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html#isAccountNonLocked--)

```
boolean isAccountNonLocked()
Indicates whether the user is locked or unlocked. A locked user cannot be authenticated.
Returns:
true if the user is not locked, false otherwise
```

**false** means the user is locked.You should return **true** from the method for the user to be not locked.